# Не переходит по ссылке на сайте selenium Web Driver Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

**Нужно что бы открывало ссылку на видео на сайте youtube.com
перепробовал уже и xpath и Linktext и selector ничего не срабатывает 
вот код**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.identity.Selector;


public class googleTest1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chrome\\chromedriver.exe");

        ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
        opt.addArguments("--disable-notifications");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //go to google.com
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        //maximize chrome window
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //google search
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name=\"q\"]")).sendKeys("youtube");

        //click on button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tsf\"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/center/input[1]")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        //click on link "youtube"
        driver.findElement(By.className("S3Uucc")).click();
        //search field on youtube.com
        driver.findElement(By.id("search")).sendKeys("Linkin Park - Numb");
        //click on button search
        driver.findElement(By.id("search-icon-legacy")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        //press on link video
        driver.findElement(By.l("Numb (Official Video) - Linkin Park")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);






    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
//click on link video
WebElement lpVideo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("путь к видео"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", lpVideo);
```